# Publishing hosted Blazor Wasm from cmdline: browser-wasm and palaformtarget x64 incompatible

Tags: blazor, webassembly, dotnet-publish

I'm trying to publish an ASP.NET hosted Blazor wasm app, but I'm having some issues with the publishing. I'd like to publish a x64 self-contained app and I'm using the following command from within the server project:

```
dotnet publish .\Wasm.Server.csproj -c Release --self-contained -r win10-x64
```

A couple of extra notes:

- I'm under the impression that since I've created the wasm project as hosted, then I should get everything I need just by publishing the server project (ie, publishing the server project will build the wasm project and copy the required files into the wwwroot of the server project and copy everything to the output folder)
- I want the server side (API) to be self contained
- I'm using the win10-x64 because the web app will be published on a windows serve box

Unfortunately, this generates the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets(196,5): error NETSDK1032: The RuntimeIdentifier platform 'browser-wasm' and the PlatformTarget 'x64' must be compatible.
```

Any clues on how to solve this? I've tested it in another box and it seems to work without any issues.

Comment: At this time WASM in the browser is 32-bit.

Comment: Hi. I've tried x86, same result. But does that mean I can't used the hosted model if I require the server side (services) to run x64?

Comment: If you are targeting the browser, this is wrong **win10-x64**. That creates a self-contained amd64 executable for Windows.

Comment: here's the thing: I'm building the server side. Since the blazor client is hosted, I was under the impression that publishing the server would also build the blazor client. The server side (services api) will be hosted in a windows server box, that's why I was specifying win10-x64. So, I'm guessing that the question is how to build and publish a solution where a blazor wasm project is hosted on a asp.net core services app.

Comment: 1) <RunAOTCompilation> property set to true to the Blazor WebAssembly app's project file. 2) Remove **--self-contained -r win10-x64**

Comment: But I'm not interested in having aot just yet. I've added a couple of notes in order to explain what I need. I can't remove the self contained option because I need the server web app (which will host the wasm app) to be published as self contained.

Comment: Solved it. The problem was the powershell profile was loading extra environment variables so that the C compiler could be used from the cmd line. Removing those extra environment variables seems to make everything work (with the self contained and win-x64 options)